# can't dump anonymous class Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, hoptoad, to-yaml

I get a strange issue on the server as below

`/!\ FAILSAFE /!\ Wed Apr 25 19:35:13 +0000 2012`
 `Status: 500 Internal Server Error`
 `can't dump anonymous class Class`

Please Have a look on the backtrace of issue [Click Here](https://gist.github.com/2492907)

FYI, Server has ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code may have referenced the type method of the Object which clashes with your Object's type attribute. Can't see your code to tell for sure. If that is the case, use a different name for your attribute.